# React native for iOS 2023

Tags: xcode14.3

I am getting the following error when running the **npx react-native run-ios** command. the project and computer settings are listed below. The error occurs even on an empty project after the **npx react-native init** command

```
2023-08-01 12:13:56.935 xcodebuild[9279:90606] DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled set via user default (DVTEnableCoreDevice=disabled)
--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:A0B18B9C-2204-4E44-ABF6-DD21454022DF, OS:16.4, name:iPhone SE (3rd generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:A0B18B9C-2204-4E44-ABF6-DD21454022DF, OS:16.4, name:iPhone SE (3rd generation) }
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Generate\ Specs /Users/daniilfilinski/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/golosnadezhdi-haixoqirbqljidfxtrqmnhpbviwz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBReactNativeSpec.build/Script-46EB2E0001CF10.sh (in target 'FBReactNativeSpec' from project 'Pods')

System:
    OS: macOS 13.4.1
    CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M2
    Memory: 111.86 MB / 8.00 GB
    Shell: 5.9 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 20.5.0 - /opt/homebrew/bin/node
    Yarn: Not Found
    npm: 9.8.0 - /opt/homebrew/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2023.07.24.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.12.1 - /Users/daniilfilinski/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 22.4, iOS 16.4, macOS 13.3, tvOS 16.4, watchOS 9.4
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2022.2 AI-222.4459.24.2221.9971841
    Xcode: 14.3.1/14E300c - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.19 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0 
    react-native: 0.71.8 => 0.71.8 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

tried reinstalling Xcode, installing a different version of react-native, running on different emulators

Comment: I m also facing the same issue, when I build new App with updated react-native version,